# How can i "unset" a class that has been declared

Tags: php, oop, class

I have a complete Form Creation System. There are many different Question Types and I have to check if the answer which the person had made is correct.

All types of Questions has its own class will is always called ItemClass and this Class is in its own File.

Everytime a Question is asked I include the File and there is the problem: I have to check different types of Questions in one PHP-File. And then there comes the error -  ItemClass already declared.

Is there any method to unset a Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your solutions and finally I got an Idea:
I renamed the Classes to each of it's type (ynItemClass, markItemClass, ...) and when I need a Item Type a made the following

```
$it = $item->item_type."ItemClass";
$test = new $it($smarty);
```

And it works!!

Have a nice Day!
Dominik

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible to "undefine" an existing class.

In your case, you should not have several classes that all have the same name : each class should have a different / distinct name, and you should modify the way you are working with those, so your code deals with classes not named `ItemClass`.

For instance, you could have :

- `ItemClass_Type1` in `itemclass_type1.php`
- `ItemClass_Type2` in `itemclass_type2.php`

and so on -- and those classes could all extend the same base class, if needed / if it makes sense.

*(For a while, I thought maybe [runkit](http://php.net/runkit) could help with the "undefining a class" idea ; but there doesn't seem to be a function to do that -- and that extension is not quite stable and shouldn't be used on a production server)*

Answer (score 6):

No.

Once a class is decalred it cannot be 'unset'

Maybe [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) could be of use to you?

Comment: Mhm I am not sure I can use that for my problem

Answer (score 2):

No. You have a design flaw.
You should have probably let the different type of questions inherit from one abstract question class and/or (1) used the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) or (2) used the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).