# how to exclude a file after including it in php?

Tags: php, require-once, php-include

After we add a file inside `Myfile.php` with:

```
require_once 'abc.php';
```

or

```
include_once 'abc.php';
```

How we will remove the file? Or how to stop the `abc.php` file content being accessed after a certain block of code?

Comment: Why? There something wrong with your logic.

Comment: yes. if its cannot possible I have to spent some 2-3 hours to change my code. I have different files with a class inside them. but some class have same names. so in case i need to access 2 different files with same class, it will throw 'class redeclared error'.

Comment: Shouldn't have classes with the same name.  If you can't avoid it (outside libraries) use name spaces: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ohh no.. I am actually using Gas ORM, which is creating table classes. so for table name `user_details` and `payment_details`, it will create classes in `user` folder and `payment` folder with `details.php` file and class - `details` ..

Comment: OK, and...  those classes have different names.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  name means namespaces ? yes different ofcourse. its table name itself like - `Model\user\details`, `Model\payment\details`.

Comment: I see.  That's not a good way for the framework to do it.  If there's not a way around it then switch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PHP, once a resource is included, it can not be *removed* or "un-included". This is the very principle of PHP file inclusion. See : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

Once the interpreter has *evaluated* your code, the job is done. All operations have been taken into account, and in order to undo the changes, you have to perform the opposite operations. For instance, if your included file declares the class `MyClass` then you would need to *undefine* it, which is also impossible for very same reason as above. See : [Unset Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236294/unset-class).

If your file actually adds *functions* and not *classes*, then since PHP 5.3, you can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). This allows you to assign functions to variables, which **can** be [unset](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.unset.php). See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691911/2228310).

If a part of your code's logic has to disappear at some point, then you did not spend enough time *designing* before *implementing*.

If you need to *undo an inclusion* because of name conflicts, the problem is pretty much the same. However, a solution in this case would be to use [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). Still, a little review of your application design should be enough to avoid such conflicts.

*Edit about frameworks :* a single framework cannot fit for each and every application. Symfony, for instance, uses namespaces absolutely everywhere to avoid any possible conflicts (yet, some occur). If your framework does not offer you the possibility to easily distinguish two model classes with the same name, then I'd say it does not fit (at least, not with your design).

Comment: if you are trying to avoid unnecessary inclusion, you can enclose the include command within a conditional. Assuming $x != TRUE, the file "thisFile_inc.php" will not be loaded or parsed in the following: `if($x=TRUE){include("thisFile_inc.php);}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. once its loaded cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround. You can include the file while output buffering is turned on. Then save the output into a variable like `$output`. Use it if you need it, otherwise, just do `unset($output)` to discard it;

```
ob_start();
include('file.php'); 
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And later on, you can do `unset($output)` when you don't need it anymore.